# Nesting displayed when mapping collection in HAML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, dictionary, nested, haml

I'm working on a Rails application, using HAML.  I needed to present a list to the user, when I stumbled upon this weird behaviour:

This code generates no output, obviously.

```
- 5.times.map do |n|
  - n + 1
```

This code generates `1 2 3 4 5`, as it's outputting the return value for the inner statement.

```
- 5.times.map do |n|
  = n + 1                # Notice the =
```

This code generates `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, as it's outputting the mapped array.

```
= 5.times.map do |n|     # Notice the =
  - n + 1
```

So far, so good...

## This code generates `1 2 3 4 5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, as it doesn't like humans.

```
= 5.times.map do |n|     # Notice the =
  = n + 1                # on both lines
```

#### This code generates `1 2 3 4 5 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, as it's nested in the `<p>`.

```
%p                       # Here we are nested one <p> deep
  = 5.times.map do |n|
    = n + 1
```

#### This code generates `1 2 3 4 5 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`, as it's double nested (and so on).

```
%p                       # Here we are nested two <p> deep
  %p
    = 5.times.map do |n|
      = n + 1
```

Does anyone have an explanation for what is happening here in the HAML internals?  Is `= n+1` both adding a string to some output buffer, and then returning it's nesting level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you are asking is very version dependent. I mean it will produce different results in upcoming version of Haml (`v4.1.0`).

But first let's find out why this output in version < `4.1.0`?

Under the hood, Haml translates templates into executable Ruby code. This job is done in [Haml::Compiler](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.7/lib/haml/buffer.rb#L119) class and you can easily debug this code:

```
require 'haml'

puts Haml::Engine.new(%q{
%p
  %p
    %p
      = 5.times.map do |i|
      = i
}).render # => produces the output
          # you have in last example
```

to find out what the associated Ruby code looks like.
With some simplifications, it looks like this:

```
haml_temp =  5.times.map do |i|
  _hamlout.push_text("      #{_hamlout.format_script_false_false_false_false_false_true_false(( i ));}\n", 0, false);
end
```

You can easily see by now, that your values are mapped to the expression:

```
_hamlout.push_text(...)
```

`_hamlout` here is an instance of `Haml::Buffer` and this is the [last line](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.7/lib/haml/buffer.rb#L119), which returns value from the `push_text` method:

```
 @real_tabs += tab_change
```

`@real_tabs` is indent level. If we use no indent, then it's `0`, when one `%p` is involved, it becomes `1` and so on. `tab_change` argument is `0` (see debugged code).

So the output for Haml version `4.0.7` is equal to the level of nesting. This is exactly how your output looks like.

But this behavior will be probably "broken" in upcoming version `4.1.0`. Compare the [last line of the same method](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/lib/haml/buffer.rb#L123) from current master branch:

```
@buffer << text
```

which will return some textual value.

Comment: Interesting.  The [commit which introduced this change](https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/04634bc3d884fa49a92713b73307b3e903c542e7) seems to be from 2013.

Comment: @bosticko https://rubygems.org/gems/haml version 4.1.0.alpha was released in november, 2013. I hope, we will eventually see it final :)

Comment: Wow! That's a long time. Definitely explains that timestamp though.  Well... probably not actually *that* long, but seems long.